# insert javascript parameter into RAZOR function CodeBehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net, razor

I have this code. In Javascript function, I want to put X  parameter (javascript var) in the Razor function `EXTENDED.ProcessDay ()`

```
 function Test() {
                var X = document.getElementById("targetID").value;
                document.getElementById("result").value = "@EXTENDED.ProcessDay(X)";
            }
```

but the code above doesn't work.
I have also tried:

```
function Test() {
                var X = document.getElementById("targetID").value;
                document.getElementById("result").value = "@EXTENDED.ProcessDay(@X)";
            }
```

but it did not work either. What would be the correct method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Javascript codes and C# do not live same time. Razor variables are "server side variables", after the page was sent to client side, they don't exist anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by they do not live same time? I think you need to refine your answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what Makif meant was that Javascript will modify things live in the page... (I click on a button, the value of an input change)
Razor will run before a page and act on it before the loading (x = 2, the input value = x, so the input when the page is ready = 2)
You can't modify a razor function with Javascript. Either you create a full JS function that do everything or you create a Razor function that do everything.

I think I'm pretty experienced in Razor but I'm still learning about JS. That's my understanding. Maybe an experienced JS programmer will arg about that.